# Can I marry my niece from a half-sister?

Tags: nikah, mahram

My father married two women, Basically my half sister and I share same father (biological) but we have different mothers. Can I marry my half sister's daughter(my half niece) ?

Answer (score 3):

You can not, your half-sister is your *mahram*, and so is her daughter.

> حُرِّمَتْ عَلَيْكُمْ ... وَبَنَاتُ الْأُخْتِ
>
> Prohibited to you [for marriage] are ... your sister's daughters ...
>
> <sup>[Quran 4:23](https://quran.com/4/23)</sup>

From [Tafsir Qurtubi:](http://www.altafsir.com/Tafasir.asp?tMadhNo=0&tTafsirNo=5&tSoraNo=4&tAyahNo=23&tDisplay=yes&Page=2&Size=1&LanguageId=1)

> والأخت ٱسم لكل أُنثى جاورتك في أصليْك أو في أحدهما
>
> "*Sister*" is the name of every female who is your sibling,
> from both sides or just one.

Also see: [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=330067) and [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/193535)